# R lubridate guess_formats duplicates vector

Tags: r, lubridate

Hello dear helpful knowledgeable R gurus and Stackoverflowers,

I'm trying to format dates consistently across a range of datasets, using guess_formats from lubridate. However, this concatenates two instances of the column.  Here's a minimal example:

```
library(lubridate)
x <- c("2014-01-18 00:00:00","2015-03-01 00:00:00","2014-05-05 00:00:00")
y <- as.Date(x, format = guess_formats(x, "Ymd HMS"))
```

Result:

```
> x
[1] "2014-01-18 00:00:00" "2015-03-01 00:00:00" "2014-05-05 00:00:00"
> y
[1] "2014-01-18" "2015-03-01" "2014-05-05" "2014-01-18" "2015-03-01"
[6] "2014-05-05"
```

Any pointers would be great!

Comment: I don't know why this happens but may I suggest `library(anytime); anydate(x)` as an alternative?

Comment: Many thanks, I'll bear that in mind, however these are pre-existing scripts used by a team and lubridate used across several scrips at the moment so I'd like to try to find out what causes it if possible. Good to have a backup!

Comment: How about using `parse_date_time`? i.e. `y <- as.Date(parse_date_time(x, "Ymd HMS"))`. But I am really puzzled why `guess_formats` is duplicating data.

Comment: I've just checked and this occurs in lubridate version 1.7.4, but not in lubridate version 1.5.6  Wondering whether and how it would be appropriate to notify package developers re a possible bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the `guess_formats`.

If you run `guess_formats(x, "Ymd HMS")` the return is not 3 formats, but 6 formats.

```
             YOmdHMS              YOmdHMS              YOmdHMS               YmdHMS               YmdHMS               YmdHMS 
"%Y-%Om-%d %H:%M:%S" "%Y-%Om-%d %H:%M:%S" "%Y-%Om-%d %H:%M:%S"  "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"  "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"  "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

Now you are passing 6 formats to as.Date which will process these and recycles x to match. If you just paste these 6 formats in as.Date you can see the result of your y vector.

```
as.Date(x, format = c("%Y-%Om-%d %H:%M:%S", "%Y-%Om-%d %H:%M:%S", "%Y-%Om-%d %H:%M:%S" , "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",  "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",  "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") 

[1] "2014-01-18" "2015-03-01" "2014-05-05" "2015-05-05" "2014-01-18" "2015-03-01"
```

The obvious solution would be to use `y <- ymd_hms(x)` as you are trying to guess this format anyway and ymd_hms already tries to parse many different versions of this format.